I tried to set a static IP address and change my pi's name. Graphics desktop died. How do I get it back?
I created a hostname for my pi:  /etc/hostname contains one line:
whiskas

/etc/hosts:
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1   whiskas
192.168.1.238   whiskas

I had tried to set /etc/dhcpcd
# Request a hostname from the network
option host_name

# Most distributions have NTP support.
#option ntp_servers

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate SLAAC address using the Hardware Address of the interface
#slaac hwaddr
# OR generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses based from the DUID
slaac private
#interface wlan0
#static routers=192.168.1.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1
#static ip_address=192.168.1.251/24

The changes that were suggested are commented out at the end.
I don't even know how to undo what I did. I don't remember what the machine used to be called, probably raspberrypi? But rather than go back, I would just like to know how to fix  the problem. The desktop immediately stopped working. Now it only boots into text mode.
In desperation, I re-edited the /etc/hosts file and put the name back to raspberry pi.
It still doesn't start up the graphical desktop.
Chatgpt suggested that I move out the config file:
mv ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi.bak

no dice. Then reinstall lxde:
sudo apt install --reinstall lxde-core lxde-common lxde-icon-theme

This worked, and I have a graphics desktop again, but (and this is where it started) no background image, no icons other than the trash can.
I'm thoroughly disgusted. Not sure how my system got corrupted, but if anyone can suggest how I can reload the graphics without wiping out everything I've got on the drive, I would appreciate that.
UPdate: I got the graphics back, sort of. I don't know what the default desktop on pi is, is it lxde? But there is a blank little rectangle in the bottom left of the screen that has a startup menu, so at least I can run the apps. But how incredibly ugly, that it was literally invisible,and I just happened to click on it.
The default on the pi looks like a gorgeous chinese painting of some kind, and there's the icons on the top of the window. That's was evaporated.
And of course, I still don't have a static ip address, I gave that up trying to get graphics to work again.

Which Pi? What OS is installed (detail including version)? Why do you want static IP?

NOTE it is unclear from your question whether you had a problem you were trying to fix or the problem was caused by the changes you made. Either way the fix is to restore from your backup.

I wanted a static ip to run qbittorrent. THis is a raspberry pi 5 running Linux raspberrypi 6.6.62+rpt-rpi-2712 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.6.62-1+rpt1 (2024-11-25) aarch64 GNU/Linux

I was trying to get it to use a static address. That didn't work, so I backed off. The graphics desktop somehow got corrupted, not sure how that happened, but I want to just reset it to how it used to be without destroying the data on the system.
And I have no way of backing it up. I will back up files with data, but backing up the operating system always seemed pointless since it changes fairly fast. All I did was change IP address, not install some weird experimental kernel.

DO NOT put details in Comments; EDIT your Question.

There's a reasonable answer to a question that is at least similar to yours on U&L SE.

Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm DOES NOT use dhcpcd by default but networkmanager.
If you REALLY want a static IP there are instructions but even Raspberry Pi Ltd. does not recommend this.
First you NEED to undo the changes you made; delete /etc/dhcpcd and restore /etc/hosts (delete the last line).
If you then want to do something ASK a question; ONLY one problem per Question.
To change hostname use raspi-config.

NOTE in future if you change ANY system file make a copy BEFORE changing.
